# WinForm C#: Datagridview combobox it is duplicating records from second line

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, devexpress

The datagridview combobox is duplicating the values ​​from the second line. How can I solve this.

Thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpxUs.png)

Code:

```
void ListagemNoCombobox()
{
    //Populando o combobox do criterio
    string[] criterios = { "Sem Critério", "3ª Série do Ensino Médio ", "2ª Série do Ensino Médio ", "1ª Série do Ensino Médio " };
    foreach (string crit in criterios)
    {
        cmbCriterio.Items.Add(crit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the method `ListagemNoCombobox()`?  Are you calling it more than once?

Comment: It looks like this method is running multiple times. Either find a better event so that it only runs once or start the method with cmbCriterio.Items.Clear() to clear existing entries before adding them.

Comment: perfect... that's right
thank you friends

Comment: void ListagemNoCombobox()
        {
            cmbCriterio.Items.Clear();
            //Populando o combobox do criterio
            string[] criterios = { "Sem Critério", "3ª Série do Ensino Médio ", "2ª Série do Ensino Médio ", "1ª Série do Ensino Médio " };
            foreach (string crit in criterios)
            {
                cmbCriterio.Items.Add(crit);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  void ListagemNoCombobox()
    {
        cmbCriterio.Items.Clear();
        //Populando o combobox do criterio
        string[] criterios = { "Sem Critério", "3ª Série do Ensino Médio ", "2ª Série do Ensino Médio ", "1ª Série do Ensino Médio " };
        foreach (string crit in criterios)
        {
            cmbCriterio.Items.Add(crit);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).